# Removing border line of a shape

Tags: plotting

Consider

```
trial = Graphics3D[{Glow[Darker[Darker[Cyan]]],Cylinder[{{6  Cos[3], 6 Sin[3], 0}, {6 Cos[4], 6 Sin[4], 0}}, 1]}]
```

This will give a cylinder. Can you help with how we can get rid of the black lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `Boxed` option:

```
Graphics3D[{Glow[Darker[Darker[Cyan]]], 
   Cylinder[{{6  Cos[3], 6 Sin[3], 0}, {6 Cos[4], 
      6 Sin[4], 0}}, 1]}, Boxed->False]
```

If you meant the outline of the cylinder, rather than the bounding box, you can use `EdgeForm[None]`:

```
Graphics3D[{Glow[Darker[Darker[Cyan]]], EdgeForm[None], 
  Cylinder[{{6 Cos[3], 6 Sin[3], 0}, {6 Cos[4], 6 Sin[4], 0}}, 1]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]